# Running mosquitto MQTT broker on a subdomain on my home server

Tags: subdomain, mqtt

I own my own domain name E.G. website.com I have a mosquitto MQTT broker running on a Windows 10 machine. I have forwarded port 1883 and it's currently running just as expected if I use my public IP address as the host E.G. `12.345.678:1883`. When I add this as a redirect to my subdomain E.G. `mqtt.webite.com` I cannot connect.

I'm brand new to this and have been fudging my way through this setup and this part I can't figure out. I'm assuming it has something to do with the web host protocol being HTTP and not MQTT but I don't know nor do I know how to change it.

Any ideas how to use a subdomain to point to my brokers IP address/port?

Comment: does *mqtt.webite.com* resolve to your IP address?

Comment: As far as I know it does.  I'm running it as a simple redirect to the IP with the port with the target not hidden meaning you'd see the new actual IP address.  The host only gives me the option for HTTP or HTTPS and this is where I think the problem is? I don't know if I need to point it to a directory and run a script or PHP or something in that directory to then point it to the IP address as a mqtt not http? this is where I'm lost.